# How can i send the current scrolling position of a scroll view to another, and reconfigure it into the second ? iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have two Views, each one has a scrollView, both of them has the same contents.
What i want to do is : When the user hits a button the second view appears and its scroll view "auto-scroll" to the same position the user scrolled on the first one.
i tried .getY and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get ScrollView y position after scrolling end by using `scrollViewDidScroll` function and send to secondView when appear.

```
var yPosition : CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
// new y position of scroll when scroll finished

self.yPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Then,pass this data to secondView and change secondView's `scroll.scrollView.contentOffset`